# How to show fitted curve for random effects?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, quadratic-form

I have a data set studying the difference pollen production among eight varities. The experiment was carried out in two locations, and pollen was collected and weighted once per week. The experiment lasted for four months, resulting in a repeated measurement data set.

To analyse which varieties has higher pollen production, I fit a linear mixed model with lmer. In data set, "pollen" is response variable, "city" is locaiton, "time" is the time point, "type" is variety. By plotting the data, I found quadratic relation between "pollen" and "time". So I fitted the model below:

```
mo <- lmer(pollen ~ time + I(time^2) + city + (time + I(time^2)|type))
```

Here I put "type" as a random effect because I would like to have the conditional mean of differnt varieties.

Here are my questions:
  1. Is it ok to have quadratic term in random part?
  2. I got the conditional means of random effect using `ranef(mo)`. I tried to get the fitted curve line by `sjp.lmer(mo, type = "pred", vars = c("time", "type")`. However, it ignored the quadratic term. Is it possible to show the fitted quadratic line for "type"?

First post, thank you in advance!